# Why is the bottom half of my site not showing up?

Tags: python, html, css, django

I added another div to bottom half of my site but it is not showing up.  I can get it to show up in a separate web page, but not when I paste the same code to the bottom of this web page.  Check out code, thanks in advance for you efforts.
OK so I understand I need to make "blogs" available in views.  I tried modifying the function that defines "blogs", I also tried adding a new function for the page but neither seemed to work.  I updated the original post with my views.py.

all_blogs.html

```
{% extends 'blog/navBarFooter.html' %}
{% block content %}
<br>
<br>
{% for blog in blogs %}
<div class="col-lg-12 col-md-8">
    <img src="{{ blog.summaryImage.url }}" height=190 width=350>
    <p>{{ blog.category }}</p>
    <a href="{% url 'pageOne' blog.id %}">
        <h2>{{ blog.title }}</h2>
    </a>
    <p>By: {{ blog.by }} | {{ blog.date|date:'M d Y'|upper }}</p>
    <p>{{ blog.summary }}</p>
    <hr color="black">
</div>
{% endfor %}

{% endblock %}
```

pageOne.html:

```
{% extends 'blog/navBarFooter.html' %}
{% block content %}

<!-- *************SHOWING UP ON WEBPAGE******************* -->

<h1 class="text-center mt-3" id="blogdetailtitle">{{ blog.title }}</h1>
<h5 class="text-center mt-3" id="blogdetailtitle">By: {{ blog.by }} | {{ blog.category }}</h5>

<hr color="black">
<div class="col-lg-12 col-md-8">


    <img id="imgLeft" src="{{ blog.pageOneImage.url }}" height=190 width=350>
    <p id="textLeft">{{ blog.pageOne | safe }}</p>
    <br>
    <br>
    <hr>
    <img id="imgRight" src="{{ blog.pageTwoImage.url }}" height=190 width=350>
    <p id="textLeft">{{ blog.pageTwo | safe }}</p>
    <br>
    <br>
    <hr>
    <img id="imgLeft" src="{{ blog.pageThreeImage.url }}" height=190 width=350>
    <p id="textLeft">{{ blog.pageThree | safe }}</p>
    <br>
    <br>
    <hr>
    <img id="imgRight" src="{{ blog.pageFourImage.url }}" height=190 width=350>
    <p id="textLeft">{{ blog.pageFour | safe }}</p>

    <br><br><br><br>
    <hr>
</div>
<!-- *************NOT SHOWING UP ON WEBPAGE******************* -->
{% for blog in blogs %}
<div class="row">

    <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6">

        <img src="{{ blog.summaryImage.url }}" height=190 width=350>
        <p>{{ blog.category }}</p>
        <a href="{% url 'pageOne' blog.id %}">
            <h2>{{ blog.title }}</h2>
        </a>
        <p>{{ blog.date|date:'M d Y'|upper }}</p>
        <p>{{ blog.summary }}</p>

    </div>
    {% endfor %}
</div>


{% endblock %}
```

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404
from .models import Blog


def all_blogs(request):
    blogs = Blog.objects.order_by('category')
    return render(request, 'blog/all_blogs.html', {'blogs': blogs})


def pageOne(request, blog_id):
    blog = get_object_or_404(Blog, pk=blog_id)
    return render(request, 'blog/pageOne.html', {'blog': blog})


def all_blogsT(request):
    blogs = Blog.objects.order_by('category')
    return render(request, 'blog/pageOne.html', {'blogs': blogs})
```

Comment: did you make sure 'blogs' is made available by the view? In this case, if 'blogs' is undefined, the for loop will skip that section just as you describe

Comment: Thanks, I updated the original post with my views.py.

Answer (score 0):

Your first half seems to be operating on a single `blog` variable, and not a list of blogs like in your second half.

So, consider removing the loop from your second half, and it should work.

If this is not the desired output you want, make sure you are using a list of blogs that actually contains elements for your second half. Currently it seems that your list `blogs` is either undefined or empty.